# T-SQL query resulting in list of none commited data in current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Running Microsoft SQL Server, I have 2 SELECT´s that seperately works like they should, 1. is listing all departments, and 2. is listing appartments with data submitted in curent month, but I have get these "joined" so that my result will be a list of the departments that have not submitted data.

**1. SELECT** (*Giving me all departments*):

```
select distinct Department 
from (select Department
      from EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
      union all
      select Department
      from EmploymentUser)a
order by Department;
```

`

**2. SELECT** (*Giving me departments with submitted data current month*):

```
SELECT Department
FROM EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
WHERE (Month(CommitDateTime) <= Month((getdate())) 
  AND Month(CommitDateTime) >= Month((getdate()))) 
  AND (YEAR(CommitDateTime) <= YEAR((getdate())) 
  AND YEAR(CommitDateTime) >= YEAR((getdate())))
```

I have tried using `WHERE Department NOT IN ()` with SELECT 2 in it on SELECT 1, but with out any luck

Can anyone help me on how I can make a select that gives me a list of departments that have not yet committed data?

Comment: FYI, don't use syntax functions on your columns like that in  your `WHERE`; it causes the query to be non-SARGable. For dates, use date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

`EXCEPT` can be used to exclude matching rows.
The `EOMONTH` function can be used to determine the current month.
To exclude duplicate rows, it is sufficient to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

For example, the query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT Department FROM EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
UNION
SELECT Department FROM EmploymentUser
EXCEPT
SELECT Department FROM EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
WHERE EOMONTH(CommitDateTime)=EOMONTH(GETDATE())
```